# Does WS-Federation depend on Kerberos?

Tags: ws-trust

If WS-Federation/WS-Trust are deployed as part of a service to expose consumable ADFS endpoints, is there a dependency on Kerberos?

For example, if Web Application Proxy (WAP) servers were being implemented as part of an ADFS roll-out and the WAP severs were not joined to the domain, will this limit the ability to consume WS-Federation/WS-Trust endpoints exposed by ADFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, WS-Federation/WS-Trust is independent of Kerberos. Kerberos is just one option out of a range of authentication mechanisms that can be used in combination with WS-Federation/WS-Trust but it is not the only one, nor is it a requirement. Also, proxy servers may be deployed independently of the authentication mechanisms for WS-Federation/WS-Trust unless you want to apply restrictions on those mechanisms.

Comment: Z - What other authentication mechanisms are available for WS-Federation/WS-Trust?

When you say restrictions, what do you mean?

Comment: The WS-Federation and WS-Trust protocols do not actually limit the authentication mechanisms that can be used with them, but your proxy may block e.g. client certificate authentication.

Comment: Are you able to provide the other types of authentication mechanisms e.g. SAML?

Comment: It is possible to use a SAML Assertion inside of a WS-Federation or WS-Trust protocol message indeed.